# sudden page cannot be displayed message for my web application hosted in IIS

Tags: .net, iis

I have a web page say MyPage.aspx, there is a button which when clicked gives page cannot be displayed.

When right clicked and checked in properties I see res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm#http://MyDomain/MyPage.aspx as URL.

When I do the same operation from local machine(Machine which has the application hosted in IIS) it works fine, but when I access this page from other machine on local network or out of local network, I get this page cannot be diaplayed error.

Any Ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: On your local machine, if you type http://MyDomain/ does it load correctly?

Comment: yes it loads the page whereas when I click on the butoon I get page cannot be displayed with res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm#http://MyDomain/MyPage.aspx  in URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a very generic error message, so it's quite difficult to diagnose. I recently encounted this issue after migrating several web applications to a new hosting environment. For me, there were two issues that needed resolving. All of my issues revolved around Active Directory, Windows Authentication and Permissions.

**First Issue**

Our applications use Windows Authentication, however for some reason (probably environmental), the default provider order needed to be switched from **Negotiate then NTLM** to **NTLM then Negotiate**. You change this in the Windows Authentication\Providers section of IIS. After applying this change, some users reported immediate success. Unfortunately not all users.

**Second Issue**

The second issue turned out to be related to the nature of how the host had set up the servers (again), this time revolving around Permssions. Some users were getting through, others weren't. It turned out those getting through were either Admin users, or users on a different Domain Group. What needed to happen was to have OUR user's domain group to be given READ permission to (at least) the Folders where the applications reside.

Hopefully this helps a few people who stumble across this. It took me a long time and a lot of arguing with our new hosting provider to make these changes! I wont mention their name here... but they're well established, so I can imagine many others will encounter this issue!